# How can I make one function open a file, write to it then close the file, before the next function writes to it?

Tags: json, unity-game-engine, save, file-writing

I am trying to write data into a file. Want I want to do is to have each function open a file if it exists, write to it and then close it before the next function. Below is the code I got so far which does write to a file but not how I want it as mentioned.

For example, I want GetInitialRoomData() to first open, write and close the file. Then the next function GetInitialTargetData() open, write and close the file. Any ideas / code would be appreciated? Thanks!

```
void WriteInitialDataToFile()
    {
        string path = Application.persistentDataPath + fileName;
        if (!File.Exists(path))
        {           
            File.WriteAllText(path, "");            
        }

        GetInitialRoomData();
        GetInitialTargetData();

        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(saveDataList);
        Debug.Log(json);
        File.AppendAllText(path, json);
    }

    void GetInitialRoomData()
    {
        foreach (GameObject roomObject in GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Cell"))
        {
            saveRoomObject = new SaveRoomData(roomObject.name, roomObject.transform.position);
            saveDataList.Add(saveRoomObject);
        }
    }

    void GetInitialTargetData() 
    {
        foreach (GameObject targetObject in GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Target")) 
        {
            saveTargetObject = new SaveRoomData(targetObject.name, targetObject.transform.position, targetObject.transform.eulerAngles);
            saveDataList.Add(saveTargetObject);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you explain more what exactly you want? I don't see where `GetInitialRoomData` or `GetInitialTargetData` would read/write any file ... the only method which does this is `WriteInitialDataToFile` .... You want them to separate and each method does its own writing?

Comment: Yes. I want each method to write its own data in, then the next method writes it data. I need each data seperate in the json file. E.g. a section of roomCoordinates, then the next section the targetObject coordinates and so on

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is not how to open and write a file, you already did it by using `File.AppendAllText` function. 
You can not serialize a `List` directly when using `SerializeObject` function. And finally in your case, `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(saveDataList);` will return empty string and so your file will be empty too.
Use a Class or an Array instead ([Read More](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/JsonUtility.ToJson.html))

Comment: Currenlty, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(saveDataList) is writing to my file. It does not write an empty string. I am using 2 serializable classes. The 1st one is a global List<SaveRoomData> objects which is the saveDataList. The second serializable class has multiple constructors, initialisinh the data required to be stored. Currently, it is printing to file each object in consecutive ordering e.g. roomCoordinates, targetData, staticObjects and so on. Instead i want it to first write in all the roomCoordinates, then targetData position, then staticObjects and so on. Not bundle them in a string.